# ffmpeg dont work like console

Tags: ffmpeg, wsh

This works fine at console

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -vf scale=-1:360 -b:v 300k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 500k c.mp4 2> output.txt
```

then i try this live. didnt get a-log.txt file.

```
Set WScript = Server.CreateObject("WSCRIPT.SHELL")

    WScript.Run("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ffmpegfile\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\videos\a.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -vf scale=-1:360 -b:v 300k -maxrate 300k -bufsize 500k C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\videos\new\a.mp4 2> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\videos\new\a-log.txt")

    Set WScript = nothing
```

How can i run this.
thanks.

Comment: if i use -vstats_file C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\videos\new\a-log.txt. this works but i need full info.

Comment: 2> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\videos\new\a-log.txt version give only 0 kb video and no txt file

Comment: i really need help.  how can this work? anyone?

Comment: possibly set bWaitOnReturn to true [maybe your script is exiting so killing its child process--ffmpeg]? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx